# how can I count same products in order table in laravel eloquent? I`m new Laravel user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Here is my Orders table . How many same product are sell.

```
order_id     product_id     price
 1                2          100 
 2                3           50
 3                2          100
 4                3           50
 5                1          150
 6                2          100
```

I needed

```
  List   product_id  total_count
     1        2          3 
     2        3          2 
     3        1          1
```

Comment: post what you already tried

Comment: You need to provide code so people can understand the issues you are having. Then we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your query n LARAVEL Eloquent in this way.

```
$response = \DB::table('orders')
            ->select('product_id as List', \DB::raw('COUNT(product_id) as total_count'), 'product_id')
            ->groupBy('product_id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: That's not using Laravel Eloquent, that is using the DB facade.

Comment: Create a Model class name `Orders` and `Product` and define table name in both classes. Replace `\DB::table('orders')` with `Order::select('product_id as List', \DB::raw('COUNT(product_id) as total_count'), 'product_id')->groupby('product_id')->get();`. Please mention your code here as well for more help.

Comment: That is query builder not eloquent, you should use eloquent as asked.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it, you can use the below code, it is written in Laravel Eloquent as you asked:

```
$products = Orders::select('product_id', DB::raw('count(product_id) AS total_count'))->groupBy('product_id')->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

try something like this

```
$product_count= DB::table('orders')->select('product_id', DB::raw('count(product_id) as product_id'))->groupBy('product_id')->get();
```

Group By product ID and take the count of products in order